# TextBox LostFocus does not fire

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with LostFocus event it does not fire when I click on the background.I read some stuff about focus logic and keyboard focus but I could not find a way to get the focus from a control a like textbox when there is only one of them

XAML:

```xml
<Grid Height="500" Width="500">
    <TextBox Height="23" Width="120" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" LostFocus="textBox1_LostFocus"  />
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: anything in this case a grid which is in a window

Comment: try to set the background color of your TextBox, to see if it completely covers the grid. If so, you continue clicking on TextBox, by the way. Add another control, to the grid and click on it, in order to make a valid test.

Comment: @Tigran when I add another textbox and switch to it LostFocus fires and the grid I checked that it is not wrapping the textbox so I am definitly clicking the grid.

Comment: You'll have to click on something that actually *wants* the focus.  The grid isn't it.  It has no use for keyboard input.

Answer (score 5):

You must use the following tunnelling event : PreviewLostKeyboardFocus on your textbox

> Tunneling: Initially, event handlers at the element tree root are
>   invoked. The routed event then travels a route through successive
>   child elements along the route, towards the node element that is the
>   routed event source (the element that raised the routed event).
>   Tunneling routed events are often used or handled as part of the
>   compositing for a control, such that events from composite parts can
>   be deliberately suppressed or replaced by events that are specific to
>   the complete control. Input events provided in WPF often come
>   implemented as a tunneling/bubbling pair. Tunneling events are also
>   sometimes referred to as Preview events, because of a naming
>   convention that is used for the pairs.

Comment: Well I know when you have more than one control lostFocus will fire while switching between controls I am trying to find a way to make LostFocus event fire when I click the background if it is possible.

Comment: Why your textbox must loose focus when you click on the background?

Comment: @Emre: use PreviewLostKeyboardFocus event on your textbox

Comment: @Steven if there is only one control TextBox won't lose the keyboard focus I have also tried that I think there is no way to accomplish what I am trying with a simple solution I think the only way to do is wrting a custom container which will have MouseDown event handler and whenever it is clicked it will set the focusedItem in it's focus scope to null that way TextBox's LostFocus event will fire.

Comment: @Emre: MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" on your window will let you know when your user click somewhere else than your textbox. Thus you can simulate a lost focus because this event wont be raised if the user click on the textbox

Comment: `MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"`on the Window worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The following behavior will fix this:

```
public class TextBoxUpdateOnLostKeyboardFocusBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.LostKeyboardFocus += OnKeyboardLostFocus;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.LostKeyboardFocus -= OnKeyboardLostFocus;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }
    }

    private void OnKeyboardLostFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;

        if (textBox != null && e.NewFocus == null)
        {
            // Focus on the closest focusable ancestor
            FrameworkElement parent = (FrameworkElement) textBox.Parent;
            while (parent is IInputElement && !((IInputElement) parent).Focusable)
            {
                parent = (FrameworkElement) parent.Parent;
            }

            DependencyObject scope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(textBox);
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(scope, parent);
        }
    }
}
```

You can attach it to your TextBox as follows:

```
 <TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors1:TextBoxUpdateOnLostKeyboardFocusBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>              
</TextBox>
```