# LostKeyboardFocus event not firing when textbox loses focus

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, mvvm-light

I am using the MVVM pattern with the help of MVVM light. When I click a button I change the visibility property that the textboxs' visibility is bound to. When I lose focus, the trigger should execute and collapse the textbox. The problem is that the textbox never loses focus.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" 
                 Text="{Binding TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 Visibility="{Binding TextBoxVisibility}"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                 Height="30" Width="100"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostKeyboardFocus">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CollapseTextBoxCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

`CollapseTextBoxCommand`changes the `TextBoxVisibility` property to Visibility.Collapsed.

Here is the button

```
<Button Name="AddButton"
            Command="{Binding ShowTextBoxCommand}"
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></button>
```

ShowTextBoxCommand changes the `TextBoxVisibility` property to Visibility.Visibile.

[Here is a recorded screencapture of the problem I'm talking about.](https://gfycat.com/DependentWelllitHorsemouse)

What should happen, is that when I click off the textbox, it should collapse the visibility.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at this older stackoverflow question [TextBox LostFocus does not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313192/textbox-lostfocus-does-not-fire) . I tried out a few things on a dummy project, and I couldn't get it to work with LostKeyboardFocus or PreviewLostKeyboardFocus as the other question suggests.

What I did try and I can confirm it worked, was to create an eventtrigger on the WPF window itself, to detect when clicking somewhere else other than the textbox:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowTextBoxCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Of course you can use MouseDown if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll do some more research to figure out my problem and I think you're pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does nothing to the MVVM pattern, so I tried to replicate your issue simply using a `Button`, a `CheckBox` and a `TextBox`, where the `CheckBox` acts as a focusable control to help to remove the focus from the `TextBox`. Please try the following code snippet.

xaml:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
    <TextBox Name="textBox"
             Text="Text is coming"
             LostKeyboardFocus="TextBox_LostKeyboardFocus" />
    <Button Content="getFocusButton"
            Click="AddButton_Click" />
    <CheckBox Content="dummyCheck" />
</UniformGrid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void TextBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Based on your screen capture, the reason I think why your `LostKeyBoardFocus` event is not fired is because when your `TextBox` is focused, the black background you clicked is not focusable, so that the focus on `TextBox` is not lost at all.

Therefore, in my code snippet, I add a `CheckBox`. When `TextBox` is focused, its `Visibilty` will be collapsed once the  `CheckBox` is clicked and focused.